# Jmstemplate queue versioning

Tags: json, queue, mq, jmstemplate

I’m using JmsTemplate with mq to send and receive json messages via TextMessage.  There will be multiple message producers writing json to my queue so I’m wondering if there’s a standard approach to queue & object versioning.  Something similar to rest api versioning where the endpoint url would include a version e.g. api/v1/myendpoint

I guess I could include a version within the queue name but is there a better or standard approach to this?

Comment: How about using a custom message property?